# Application is not available - When deploying docker image on Openstack 3.10

Tags: docker, glassfish, openshift

I was successfully deployed glassfish docker image on Openshift OKD 3.10
and I can create pods on it. However when I access the url that openshift created
I got the error "Application is not available"

Comment: Dockerfile

FROM glassfish
ADD init_gf.sh /home
RUN chmod +x /home/init_gf.sh
CMD /home/init_gf.sh
Glassfish admin area)
EXPOSE 8080 4848

Comment: init_gf.sh

#!/bin/sh

echo "AS_ADMIN_PASSWORD=
AS_ADMIN_NEWPASSWORD=password" >> /home/gf-password.txt
asadmin --user=admin --passwordfile=/home/gf-password.txt change-admin-password --domain_name domain1
rm /home/gf-password.txt
asadmin start-domain
echo "AS_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password" >> /home/gf-password.txt
asadmin --user=admin --passwordfile=/home/gf-password.txt enable-secure-admin
rm /home/gf-password.txt
asadmin --user=admin stop-domain
asadmin start-database
asadmin start-domain -v